# Google Cloud Datastore and service accounts: limit access permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-iam

### Background

I have a Google Cloud Project with:

- Datastore (Firebase mode)
- 2 Service accounts

I have two application that using those service accounts. Each application is using different kind (`kind1` and `kind2`).

I looking for a way to limit the access of:

- Service account 1 to `kind1` only
- Service account 2 to `kind2` only

### Questions

1. How to do it?
2. Is this possible to define permission, like `readonly` or `writeonly`? So, even if service account have permission to specific kind, still he can do limited operation on this kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such permissions or roles in GCP to limit access to datastore per kind. Your only way to do this is to control it on your backend application service(Nodejs, Python ...etc).

Consult the full permission list for datastore here[1]

[1]https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam#iam_roles

Comment: When you say "control it on your backend application service" do you mean not use the service account and write your own API to provide the data?  I don't see how the backend could otherwise limit the kinds that the service account could access.